# Deserialise JSON and get the datatypes

Tags: c#, sql, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am a begginer in C# and have been struggling to solve this issue.

1. I have a Json file.
2. I need to deserialise it and insert the data into SQL.
3. The Json file looks something like this:

   ```
   {
       "records": [
       {
           "class": "Abc",
           "id": "7720170378514849999",
           "fields": {
               "name": "xyz",
               "created_at": "2015-02-26 15:06:48 UTC",
               "updated_at": "2017-05-08 15:31:45 UTC",
               "domain": "domainname",
               "month": null,
               "secure": true,
               "filters": null,
               "users_counter": 373
           },
           "links": {
           }
       },
       {
           "class": "User",
           "id": "7765907511856219999",
           "fields": {
               "first_name": "aaa",
               "last_name": "bbb",
               "email": "aaa@domain.com",
               "timezone": null,
               "local": null,
               "unsubscribe": false,
               "address_verified": false
           },
           "links": {
               "Abc_id": "7720170378514849999"
           }
       },
   }
   ```
4. My code so far:

   ```
   public void doConvert()
   {
       string unzippedFileName = "c:\\tar\\finish\\UnzippedFile.json";


       List<dynamic> allEntities = new List<dynamic>();

       try
       {
           var deserialisedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>
           (System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@unzippedFileName));
           var records = deserialisedJson.records;

           foreach (var item in records)
           {
               string itemString = item.ToString();
               var deserialisedItem = 
               JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>>
             (itemString);
               var className = deserialisedItem["class"];
               var classId = deserialisedItem["id"];
               dynamic classFields = deserialisedItem["fields"];

               var deserialisedClassFields = 
               JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>>
               (classFields.ToString());

               dynamic classLinks = deserialisedItem["links"];
               var deserialisedClassLinks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>>(classLinks.ToString());


               ParseIntoType(className);                    
               ParseIntoType(classId);



               foreach (KeyValuePair<dynamic, dynamic> entry in deserialisedClassFields)
               {
                   ParseIntoType(entry.Key);
               }

               foreach (KeyValuePair<dynamic, dynamic> entry in deserialisedClassLinks)
               {
                   ParseIntoType(entry.Key);
               } 


               buildsqlstatements() // My issue is here


           }

       }
       catch (Exception ee)
       {
           Log.ErrorFormat("Exception:{0}", ee.ToString());
       }
   }

   public void ParseIntoType(dynamic itemTobeParsed)
   {

       new Dictionary<Type, Action>{
          {typeof(bool), () =>  boolEntityList.Add(itemTobeParsed)},
          {typeof(int),  () => intEntityList.Add(itemTobeParsed)},
          {typeof(BigInteger),  () => bigIntEntityList.Add(itemTobeParsed)},
          {typeof(double),  () => doubleEntityList.Add(itemTobeParsed)},
          {typeof(DateTime),  () => dateTimeEntityList.Add(itemTobeParsed)},
          {typeof(string),  () => stringEntityList.Add(itemTobeParsed)},
          {typeof(TextReader),  () => textEntityList.Add(itemTobeParsed)},             

          }[itemTobeParsed.GetType()]();


   }
   ```

Details:

The idea is to delete everything that is in the database and re-create everything on each run. So it will delete/drop the tables and recreate the same table with the latest data.

For example for Users table, I will first drop if any (from yesterday's run) Users_temp table is there, then create Users_temp table, insert the latest data into this table, then drop Users table and then rename Users_temp to Users table. My issue here is that in order to create the Users_temp table I have to define its column types. So I have to get the data type of first_name, which would come in as string and then I will have to somehow map it to varchar(255) and then build the sql statement.

Create table Users(
first_name varchar(255)
lastname varchar(255)
timezone datetime
);

```
         //string createTmpTable = "create table "+className+" ((column = deserialised key from fields, datatype = its datatype))";
```

Right now what happens is everything gets parsed as string. Even the timezone or any int data also gets parsed as string. So I am unable to build the sql statement because I am not getting the correct datatype.  I am assuming this is because of these lines:

```
    foreach (var item in records)
            {
                string itemString = item.ToString();
                var deserialisedItem = 
   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>>(itemString);
```

because I am converting the item to itemString, everything becomes a string. JsonConvert.DeserializeObject only takes in String parameter so I cannot pass anything else there. Is there any way I can recover the original data type there?

Comment: Not if it isn't passed along anywhere. your best guess at this point is to make a model that could contain a row in your JSON, and have your deserialisation cast or parse the values according to your model.

Comment: Thanks Timothy. Yes I thought of making a model but as you see the class Users and class Abc have different values in "fields" node. There are thousands of class in the json file and I cannot use a model for each class. Moreover, the requirement given to me is that, it has to be dynamic enough to receive and parse any class type that comes in or might come in future, get its data type and insert into the table dynamically. How would I do that without deseralising the json to its respective class?

Comment: that is pretty tricky, maybe assume "safe" large / safe datatypes based on the way the data is notated in JSON? ( if wrapped in `""`, but not a date notation, it's probably a `string`, if not wrapped and no decimal points, assume it's a `long`, if it has a decimal point, assume a `decimal`, etc?)

Comment: (your main problem i think is ensuring the data in the JSON always fits inside your strongly typed model)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a typed model and tell JsonConvert to leave fields as null if it can't find them in the json string. You can leverage that and provide all possible fields in a typed model structure. You gain the benefit of verifing the data is correctly typed before it goes into the database.

```
public class Record
{
    public string @class {get; set;}
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<RecordField> fields { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,string> links { get; set; }
}

public class RecordField
{
    // fields from first object in the array
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
    public string domain { get; set; }
    public int month { get; set; }
    public bool secure { get; set; }
    public List<string> filters { get; set; }
    public int user_count { get; set; }

    // fields from second object in the array
    public int first_name { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

To make JsonConvert aware of possible missing fields this you need to set the following settings before the conversion:

```
var settings =
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
    };
var records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Record>>(json, settings);
```